# Why does a text file not save what is written into it after I terminate the code?

Tags: python

So, I'm making a password generator and trying to save it to a text file. This is how it looks:

```
import string
from random import *

characters = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation  + string.digits
password =  ("".join(choice(characters) for x in range(randint(8, 16))))
print(password)

choice = input("What is your password for?")
F = open("Passwords.py", "w")
F.write("\n" + choice + ": " + password)
F.close()
```

But for some reason, the text file only saves the most recent password. And for this to actually be applicable, I need the text file to save more than one password. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Look into what "append" does (open the file using `a` instead of `w`)

Comment: Refer this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/python-open-built-in-function-difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing `open("Passwords.py", "w")` the W for write is overwriting the existing file data you can use `open("Passwords.py", "a")` to append data to the file and this will add you new password without overwriting the existing.
You can do as following

```
with open("Passwords.py", "a") as f:
    f.write("\n" + choice + ": " + password)
```

when using with on a file it will close it automatically after executing the write()

Answer (score 0):

you are using write not append

anything you type will be overwritten

```
F = open("passwords.txt", "a")
f.append("/n" + choice + ": " + password)
```